# I am getting while launching my turtlebot pn RVIZ

Tags: gazebo, rviz, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using turtlebot for my obstacle avoid robot using ultrasonic sensors.I am using 8 ultrasonic sensors.I dont know where the error is but ths it is successfully seen in gazebo but while I am launching it in rviz.
`[ERROR] [1596993808.761522983]: Failed to build tree: parent link [base_footprint] of joint [sonar_front_joint] not found.  This is not valid according to the URDF spec. Every link you refer to from a joint needs to be explicitly defined in the robot description. To fix this problem you can either remove this joint [sonar_front_joint] from your urdf file, or add "" to your urdf file.
[robot_state_publisher-3] process has died [pid 4060, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/robot_state_publisher/state_publisher __name:=robot_state_publisher __log:=/home/lekhasree/.ros/log/09d44e52-da65-11ea-afc1-e8d0fc91b2fd/robot_state_publisher-3.log].
log file: /home/lekhasree/.ros/log/09d44e52-da65-11ea-afc1-e8d0fc91b2fd/robot_state_publisher-3*.log

PLese help me out with this error

The urdf file is [https://github.com/Lekha03/urdf-of-ultrasonic-sensors-with-turtlebot.git[link](https://github.com/Lekha03/urdf-of-ultrasonic-sensors-with-turtlebot.git%5Blink) text](https://github.com/Lekha03/urdf-of-ultrasonic-sensors-with-turtlebot.git)

In this I have inserted the required files. **Turtlebot isnt visible in RVIZ, what should I do.**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359058/i-am-getting-while-launching-my-turtlebot-pn-rviz/) by [sree](https://answers.ros.org/users/56825/sree/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2020-08-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You did not specify the link `base_footprint` in your urdf file. I assume this link is specified in the turtlebot description, which you should include in your urdf.

---

Originally posted by [rfn123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27865/rfn123/) with karma: 146 on 2020-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sree](https://answers.ros.org/users/56825/sree/) on 2020-08-10**:
Thank you ...It is not showing errors .But my turtlebot is not visible in RVIZ.,only a rectangular is being visible.

**Comment by [rfn123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27865/rfn123/) on 2020-08-10**:
You need to add RobotModel in the Rviz Panel in order to see the turtlebot

**Comment by [sree](https://answers.ros.org/users/56825/sree/) on 2020-08-10**:
Yeah I am Inserting But no turtlebot is visible.Only rectangular box is visible.

**Comment by [sree](https://answers.ros.org/users/56825/sree/) on 2020-08-10**:
Can please check the files.Should I insert anything more for turtelbot to be visible.

**Comment by [Tahir M.](https://answers.ros.org/users/23517/tahir-m./) on 2020-08-11**:
If you don't have a real robot than you might have to include [joint state publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher) to fake the joints. You might be seeing now only the fixed joints so for non-fixed you need joint state publisher.

**Comment by [sree](https://answers.ros.org/users/56825/sree/) on 2020-08-11**:
Yeah, I did It but a BOX is being Visible. Cant I visualize my gazebo world on RVIZ

**Comment by [rfn123](https://answers.ros.org/users/27865/rfn123/) on 2020-08-11**:
I am not sure if the urdf included in your link is the actual one you are using, but from the commented parts I see that you are specifying boxes as visuals, hence the box in Rviz.

```
<visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
      <geometry>
        <box size="0.02 0.01 0.01"/>
      </geometry>
</visual>
```

You need to specify meshes if you want them to be visible in Rviz